# How to make wget work on a Ubuntu server that connects to a router?

Tags: ubuntu, wget, router

I cannot make command wget work behind a router. Here is my situation and network settings.

In organization A's network, I have a router (R) which connects a few servers (X, Y, Z), and R is resides in A's network.
R has IP like 172.12.34.56
X has IP like 192.168.98.76 under R with portal 2210. In another word, 192.168.98.76 is X's IP assigned by R whose IP assigned by A is 172.12.34.56.
I usually VPN to A, then get to X via router with the following command, just to give you an idea of this:

```
  ssh -p 2210 myUsername@172.12.34.56
  # after prompted with password, I'm on X
```

Now I'm on X, and need use wget to download something such as

```
  wget https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/
  # output below:
  # --2019-05-15 01:02:03-- https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/
  # Resolving ftp.gnu.org ... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
  # wget: unable to resolve host address 'ftp.gnu.org'
```

The file of /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
      source /etc/network/interfaces.d/* # there's no file in this .d folder
      # The loopback network interface
      auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback
      # The primary network interface
      auto eno1
      iface eno1 inet static
      address 192.168.98.76 # I used X's ip under router
      gateway 172.12.34.56 # I used the router's ip
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222
```

Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: The wget error message says: `unable to resolve host address 'ftp.gnu.org'`. So you most probably have an issue with DNS.
Either your nameserver is unable to resolve the name, or you are not able to talk to your nameserver from X. This might be intentional setup by A's network administration department to block access to the internet from X.
Have you tried the command `nslookup www.gnu.org` on X? It should give you additional info on why the DNS lookup failed.

Comment: Just to be sure about the IP addresses. You use `ssh -p 2210 myUsername@172.12.34.56`. That seems to be your router address? But you expect to be on X afterwards? But X's IP address is 192.168.98.76. So this is NATed and the port is forwarded by the router? Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Jochen, thanks a lot first. nslookup www.gnu.org returns "server can't find www.gnu.org.mycompany.com: REFUSED", where mycompany is my company name

Comment: Yes, after ssh, I'm on X, -p 2210 tells the portal number. 192.168.98.76 is the X's IP assigned by R whose IP assigned by A is 172.12.34.56.

Comment: Seems your DNS server appended `mycompany.com` to your DNS query. This way, it only allows resolution of corporate domain names. You will not be able to look up anything outside this network. You could change the nameserver to `8.8.8.8`, the google nameserver. But I suggest, you test if it works first: `nslookup gnu.org 8.8.8.8`. But I guess you will not even be able to reach public internet IP addersses from X. That seems to be intentional. But give it a try, anyways.